# Numpy equivalent of list.index

Tags: python, numpy

In a low-level function that is called many times, I need to do the equivalent of python's list.index, but with a numpy array.  The function needs to return when it finds the first value, and raise ValueError otherwise.  Something like:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np_index(a, 1)
0
>>> np_index(a, 10)
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 10 not in array
```

I want to avoid a Python loop if possible.  `np.where` isn't an option as it always iterates through the entire array; I need something that stops once the first index is found.

---

**EDIT**: Some more specific information related to the problem.

- About 90% of the time, the index I'm searching for is in the first 1/4 to 1/2 of the array.  So there's potentially a factor of 2-4 speedup at stake here.  The other 10% of the time the value is not in the array at all.
- I've profiled things already, and the call to `np.where` is the bottleneck, taking up at least 50% of the total runtime.
- It is not essential that it raise a `ValueError`; it just has to return something that obviously indicates that the value isn't in the array.

I will probably code up a solution in Cython, as suggested.

Comment: So you have a numpy array or what?

Comment: Yes; I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Have you profiled your code so you _really know_ that `where` is the bottleneck. You may show that part of your code. AFAIK functionality you are looking for does not exists in `numpy`. Thanks

Comment: I concur with @eat. I don't think there is a method in numpy to do what you're asking, especially returning the `ValueError`. If you want to avoid python loops, I would say you should code your own function in `cython`, which should be fast and do exactly what you want. I also agree that you should profile your code and see that using `nonzero` or `where` and then finding the `min` index is actually the bottleneck in your code. Instead, if you call the function many times, the issue should be that you figure out if you can use numpy to avoid many calls when a single array operation might work.

Comment: You do posses then a quite unique situation. I never faced any serious performance problems with `where` in `numpy` nor `find` in `matlab`. (although just some times plain `logical indexing` is enough for the job) I won't expect any major improvements from `cython`, unless you'll cook up a very case specific solution (as your case may be). However, care still to show us your current code around the bottleneck? Thanks

Comment: I don't suppose the array is sorted, or if you could keep a sorted copy? If so, you can do binary search.

Comment: `1 in a` checks every element of a before returning even if the very first value is `1`.  There definitely isn't a way to do this with the functions supplied by numpy.

Answer (score 10):

See my comment on the OP's question for caveats, but in general, I would do the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
np.min(np.nonzero(a == 2)[0])
```

if the value you are looking for is not in the array, you'll get a `ValueError` due to:

```
ValueError: zero-size array to ufunc.reduce without identity
```

because you are trying to take the min value of an empty array.

I would profile this code and see if it is an actual bottleneck, because in general when numpy searches through an entire array using a built-in function rather than an explicit python loop, it is relatively fast. An insistence on halting the search when it finds the first value may be functionally irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

If your numpy array is 1d array, maybe try like this:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print a.tolist().index(2)
>>> 1
```

If is not 1d, you could search trough array like:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],[2,5,6],[0,0,2]])
print a[0,:].tolist().index(2)
>>> 1

print a[1,:].tolist().index(2)
>>> 0

print a[2,:].tolist().index(2)
>>> 2
```

Comment: According to the numpy doc, numpy.ndarray.tolist returns a copy of the orignal array. Use sparingly

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I could find to what you're asking for is nonzero.  It may sound odd, but the documentation makes it look like it might have the desired result.

http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#nonzero

Specifically this part:

> a.nonzero()
>
> Return the indices of the elements that are non-zero.
>
> Refer to `numpy.nonzero` for full documentation.
>
> ### See Also
>
> numpy.nonzero : equivalent function

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> y = array([1,3,5,7])
>>> indices = (y >= 5).nonzero()
>>> y[indices]
array([5, 7])
>>> nonzero(y)                                # function also exists
(array([0, 1, 2, 3]),)
```

Where (http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#where) may also be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks, but the `y >= 5` and `nonzero(y)` hit every array element -- I'm looking for a function that returns as soon as it finds the first index.

Comment: This is on the right track, if you use `np.nonzero(y == index_value)[0][0]` it seems to replicate `y.index(index_value)` for a numpy array, though I have not tested it extensively.

Answer (score 2):

You can code it in Cython and just import from a Python script. There is no need to migrate your entire project into Cython.

```
# paste into: indexing.pyx
def index(long[:] lst, long value):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] == value:
            return i
    raise ValueError

# import in your .py code
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
from indexing import index

# example
from numpy import zeros
a = zeros(10**6, int)
a[-1] = 1

index(a, 1)
Wall time: 6.07 ms
999999

index(a, 0)
Wall time: 38.1 µs
0
```

Answer (score 0):

NumPy's [searchsorted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) is very similar to lists's index, except that it requires a sorted array and behaves more numerically. The big differences are that you don't need to have an exact match, and you can search starting from either the left or right sides. See the following examples to get an idea how it works:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([10, 20, 30])

a.searchsorted(-99) == a.searchsorted(0) == a.searchsorted(10)
# returns index 0 for value 10

a.searchsorted(20.1) == a.searchsorted(29.9) == a.searchsorted(30)
# returns index 2 for value 30

a.searchsorted(30.1) == a.searchsorted(99) == a.searchsorted(np.nan)
# returns index 3 for undefined value
```

With the last case, where an index of 3 is returned, you can handle this as you like. I gather from the name and intention of the function that it stops after finding the first suitable index.

Comment: I don't know if it can be used this way. It relies on a binary search and the OP doesn't specify that his array is already sorted.

Comment: list.index relies on a sorted array, and the "binary search" part of the documentation is just a warning for those that mix data types (i.e., `a = np.array([2.1, 3.1, 4.1], dtype=np.float16); a.searchsorted(np.float32(3.1))` returns 2, not 1 as expected)

Comment: list.index does not rely on a sorted array.

Comment: Oh right, list.index returns the first index (if any). Yes, this solution only works on sorted arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've had this problem, it was sufficient to cast the numpy array as a list:

```
a = numpy.arange(3)
print(list(a).index(2))

>>> 2
```