# How to find the index number of list that in dictionary?

Tags: python

The example list

```
{
'date': array(['06/08/2016', '06/09/2016', '06/10/2016']),
'close': array([ 923.13,  914.25,  909.42])
}
```

I try to get the Date of close is 914.25 that is list['date'][2]
but i don't know how to get index 2 for close.

Thank you.

Comment: you may consider looking at [Numpy equivalent of list.index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098046/numpy-equivalent-of-list-index) for using the second part with your already existing structure.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to add an answer. However we don't do this in questions here - if you want to add something different to the accepted answer below, feel free to add another answer. Please also don't add [solved] to titles here - I know it is popular elsewhere, but we use the tick mark to mark questions as resolved instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, if you would do this kind of queries often, you should *restructure your data* to fit the use case better. For instance, have a dictionary where the keys are amounts and dates are values. Then, you would have quick `O(1)` lookups into the dictionary by key.

But, in this state of the problem, you can solve it with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next):

```
>>> d = {
... 'date': ['06/08/2016', '06/09/2016', '06/10/2016'],
... 'close': [ 923.13,  914.25,  909.42]
... }
>>> a = 914.25
>>> next(date for date, amount in zip(d['date'], d['close']) if amount == a)
'06/09/2016'
```

Note that if the amount would not be found, `next()` would fail with a `StopIteration` exception. You can either handle it, or you can provide a default beforehand:

```
>>> a = 10.00
>>> next((date for date, amount in zip(d['date'], d['close']) if amount == a), 'Not Found')
'Not Found'
```

Comment: "Ideally, if you would do this kind of queries often, you should restructure your data to fit the use case better." - the best part of the answer!

Comment: Thank you very much. @alecxe

Comment: I love that part of his answer too. @SilentMonk

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
>>> data = { 'date': ['06/08/2016', '06/09/2016', '06/10/2016'],'close': [ 923.13,  914.25,  909.42]}
>>> data['date'][data['close'].index(914.25)]
'06/09/2016'
```

Thanks to `index()`, you are able to get the index of the required value (914.25 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Where is the example from? I don't think you can have an `array` of strings in Python.

Assuming that the Python data structure is:

```
{
    'date': ['06/08/2016', '06/09/2016', '06/10/2016'],
    'close': [923.13,  914.25,  909.42]
}
```

and the indexes of `close` always matches the indexes of `date`, then:

```
In [1]: d = {
   ...:     'date': ['06/08/2016', '06/09/2016', '06/10/2016'],
   ...:     'close': [923.13,  914.25,  909.42]
   ...: }
```

You find the index of 914.25:

```
In [2]: d['close'].index(914.25)
Out[2]: 1
```

You find the corresponding date:

```
In [3]: d['date'][1]
Out[4]: '06/09/2016'
```